# Substring on Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array structured like this

```
var array = [
                 ["a":"one", "b":"two", "c":"three", "d":"four"],
                 ["a":"five", "b":"six", "c":"seven", "d":"eight"]
              ];
```

From this array, I have to extract only values two, three, six, seven. Afterwards I have to populate a new array with those value, like this:

```
var newArray = [
                 [two, three, 1], 
                 [six, seven, 2]
              ];
```

1 and 2 are index that must be increment by 1.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `["a":"one", "b":"two"...` - This is not a valid array

Comment: I think we need a little more detail. What solutions have you tried so far? And what language are you working in?

Comment: It is an array of string

Comment: What you've posted is not syntactically valid JavaScript. Until you correct that so that you accurately describe the data structure you really have, it's hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [
        { "a": "one", "b": "two", "c": "three", "d": "four" },
        { "a": "five", "b": "six", "c": "seven", "d": "eight" }
    ],
    newArray = [];
array.forEach(function (a, i) {
    newArray.push([a.b, a.c, i + 1]);
});
```

Comment: Now I see on the newArray value "two" "three"... There is a way to visualize only two three without ""?

Comment: simple as that: `document.write(newArray[0][0]);`